# Proper way to manage stored documents on Amazon S3

Tags: file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, security

I have a lot of sensitive documents I would like to store on my amazon s3 account but I don't understand how I can securely store them without other people having access to them.

I have an authenticated website where I would like to view some documents in my bucket so I use the PHP S3 library to get the files. However, with the link:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/file.txt
```

I can access it from anywhere. Even if I use the given security features amazon offers:

```
URL signed documents with timeouts
```

People can still access my documents with the URL https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/file.txt.

Is there something I am missing about securing documents for a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control permissions on files added to s3. If you want to control access, do not set your files to public. Instead keep them private and used signed urls to provide access to other users, or load it through an authenticated gateway.